# Some doubt about pulleys

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image: This is the pulley arrangement I am inquiring of. Please pardon the improper presentation]

The image is a question which got me thinking and a doubt ocuured, if someone could clarify it, it would be highly appreciable.
I have learned that an ideal string is inextensible and 2 particles connected to the same ideal string must thus cover equal distances in equal time and we can also say  they must have the same accleration.

But I think that the i have not fully understood the system in the image.

What i think is that the 5 kg mass must have the same acceleration as the 2 kg one since they are having a common string which connects them. The point of the 5 kg mass connected to the common string must have the same acceleration (magnitude wise) as the 2 kg mass as they are connected by an ideal string.

Kindly tell where i am wrong amd what is actually happening and causing them to have different accelerations and is there a condition as such for particles connected by an ideal string to have the same acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2 particles connected to the same ideal string must thus cover equal distances in equal time

Not true in general.  Imagine swinging a ball around your head with an inextensible string.   Both your hand and the ball are connected to the string, but the ball travels much farther than your hand does in a given period of time.

To guarantee the same distance is travelled, you need at least to ensure

- the string remains taut
- the string's path does not change (it just moves along the existing path)

The second constraint is violated in your problem.  As the 5kg mass moves up and down, the middle pulley also moves up and down, and the path the string takes changes.

You can instead imagine the 5kg mass moving down by some distance $x$ and add up what that would mean in all the vertical segments to see how much the 2kg mass would have to move to accommodate.   That would give you the ratio of accelerations between the masses.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 vertical segments of the string involved (aside from the segments passing over the pulleys, which are of constant length).  $L_1$  from the left pulley to the 5 kg mass.  $L_2$ runs form the left pulley to the middle pulley; $L_3$ runs from the right pulley to the middle pulley; and $L_4$ runs from the right pulley to the 2kg mass.  The total length of string L is constant.  So, $$L=L_1+L_2+L_3+L_4$$ or $$\frac{dL}{dt}=\frac{dL_1}{dt}+\frac{dL_2}{dt}+\frac{dL_3}{dt}+\frac{dL_4}{dt}=0$$But, $$\frac{dL_1}{dt}=\frac{dL_2}{dt}=\frac{dL_3}{dt}=v_5$$where $v_5$ is the downward velocity of the 5 kg mass, and $$\frac{dL_4}{dt}=-v_2$$ where $v_2$ is the upward velocity of the 2 kg mass. So,$$v_2=3v_5$$

$$m_2(3a)=T-m_2g$$$$m_1a=m_1g-3T$$ $$(9m_2+m_1)a=(m_1-3m_2)g$$ $$a=-\frac{g}{23}$$ $m_1$ is accelerating upward at g/23.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the equation

[image]

from the free body diagram you obtain

$$m_1\,\ddot z_1=3\,T-m_1\,g\tag 1$$
$$ m_2\,\ddot z_2=T-m_2\,g\tag 2$$

(where $~T~$ is the string tension force)

for the massless string,
$$3\,z_1+z_2=l$$
where l is the string length

and because the string is inextensible $~\dot l=0~$

$$3\,\ddot z_1+\ddot z_2=0\tag 3$$

we obtained 3 equations for the 3 unknown $~\ddot z_1~,\ddot z_2~,T$

with $~m_1=5~,m_2=2$:

$$\ddot z_2=-\frac{3}{23}\,g~,\ddot z_1=\frac{1}{23}\,g~,T=\frac{40}{23}\,g$$

Comment: This solution is incorrect because $$\frac{d^2 z^2}{dt^2}+3\frac{d^2z_1}{dt^2}=0$$See my answer.

Comment: yes this is correct, I will edit my answer